# My angular method does not fire

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, json, model-view-controller

It's the first time that I'm using angular and I am a newbie in this field; the methods do not fire at all and the changes in style do not happen. I checked everything several times but I cannot find my mistake. Help me please. Thanks in advance.

Here is the angular code:

```
<script language="javascript">


    function CustomerPresenter($scope, $http) {

        $scope.Customer = {

            "CustomerName": "",
            "CustomerCode": "",
            "CustomerAmount": "",
            "CustomerAmountColor": ""
        };
        alert($scope.Customer);
        $scope.Customers = {};
        alert($scope.Customers)
        $scope.$watch("Customers", function () {

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.Customers.length; i++) {
                alert(i);
                var cust = $scope.Customers[i];
                cust.CustomerAmountColor = $scope.getColor(cust.CustomerAmount);
            }

        });

        $scope.getColor = function (Amount) {

            if (Amount == 0) {
                return "";

            }

            else if (Amount > 100) {

                return "Blue";

            }
            else {
                return "Red";
            }
            alert(Amount);
        }

        $scope.$watch("Customer.CustomerAmount", function () {

            $scope.Customer.CustomerAmountColor = $scope.
                getColor($scope.Customer.CustomerAmount);
            alert(getColor);

        });


        $scope.Add = function () {

            $http({ method: "POST", data: $scope.Customer, url: "Submit" }).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                    $scope.Customers = data;
                    alert(data);
                    $scope.Customer = {
                        "CustomerName": "",
                        "CustomerCode": "",
                        "CustomerAmount": "",
                        "CustomerAmountColor": ""
                    };
                });

        }

        $scope.Load = function () {
            $http({ method: "GET", url: "GetCustomerJSON" }).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                    $scope.Customers = data;
                    alert($scope.Customers);

                });
        }

        $scope.Load();

    }
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller('CustomerPresenter', CustomerPresenter);
</script>
```

and this is my Html:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div>

    <div ng-controller="CustomerPresenter">
        <form id="frm">
            <i> Customer Name :</i> <input name="customer.CustomerName" ng-model="Customer.CustomerName" id="txtCustomerName" type="text" />
            <br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(z => z.customer.CustomerName)
            <br />
            <i> Customer Code :</i><input name="customer.CustomerCode" ng-model="Customer.CustomerCode" id="txtCustomerCode" type="text" />
            <br />
            <br />
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(z => z.customer.CustomerCode)
            <br />
            <i>Customer Amount :</i><input name="customer.CustomerAmount" style="background-color:{{ Customer.CustomerAmountColor }}" ng-model="Customer.CustomerAmount" id="txtCustomerAmount" type="text" />

        </form>

        <br />
        <br />
        <input id="btn" type="button" value="add customer" ng-click="Add()" />

        <br />
        <div id="status" style="width:200px;height:20px"></div>
        <table id="tblCustomer">
            <tr>
                <td>Customer Name</td>
                <td>Customer Code</td>
                <td>Customer Amount</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="cust in Customers">
                <td>{{cust.CustomerName}}</td>
                <td>{{cust.CustomerCode}}</td>
                <td style="background-color: {{ cust.CustomerAmountColor }}">{{cust.CustomerAmount}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

and the methods in controller are:

```
public ActionResult Submit(Customer customerObj)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                DataAccessLayer dal1 = new DataAccessLayer();
                dal1.customers.Add(customerObj);
                dal1.SaveChanges();


            }

            DataAccessLayer dal = new DataAccessLayer();
            List<Customer> custColl = dal.customers.ToList<Customer>();
            return Json(custColl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);



        }



  public ActionResult GetCustomerJSON()
        {
            DataAccessLayer dal = new DataAccessLayer();
            List<Customer> lstCustomers = dal.customers.ToList<Customer>();

            return Json(lstCustomers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Which __method__?

Comment: Are you getting any exception in your browser console?

Comment: add and load function do not fire.

Comment: Dear @Ferus7 in the console I got these errors:TypeError: $http(...).success is not a function
    at ChildScope.CustomerPresenter.$scope.Load (Enter:85) &angular.js:14642 ReferenceError: getColor is not defined &Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @baran just two questions, why are you embedding JavaScript in your HTML file? Did you defined `CustomerPresenter` as a `Controller` or as a function?

Comment: Dear @Ferus7 I followed a tutorial and this was the way it taught.and customer presenter is like a view model